Caching a tableresult in psql for further queries
I was wondering if my thoughtprocess is somewhat reasonable or if there is a better way and what tooling to use.
Setting: I got a filter with fuzzy search and everything, this is the most "expensive" query I got
Problem: Now I am supposed to put this filter infront of all other sql queries.
Thought: There must be a way to properly cache something like this in psql?
Solution 1: create a temporary table with the name as a hash from the filterRequest with a TTL of like 60s, everytime the Filter would get triggered, the hash is checked if it exists and if it does it performs the followup query directly.
Solution 2: Cache the result in the backend itself, which sounds stupid to me coz that can be multiple 100MB and I would have to translate SQL Queries into golang, which seems redundant and out of place
Any other solutions??
EDIT: I should elaborate on the use case, it's a page showing tons of graphs and information based on the filtered data, meaning that if a "new" filter is created, it is used like 20 times within (preferably) 1s or less

Why is relying on Postgresql's built-in caching not one of your proposed solutions?

So the task is to put this filter in front of some queries. And then you yourself slip in the addendum "... and add complex caching schemes". That is how programmers lose their job. Everyone does caching wrong, you should be trying to not do it. Only do caching as a last resort if and when you properly measured performance issues that have no other solutions.

@Peter i do not seem to be understanding the built-in caching, for some reason I find it not comprehending. But I went for the fallback Gimby mentioned aswell. I pushed it to the testers without caching and told em to properly investigate performance differences and if it becomes and issue I will start looking into caching aswell.
